# PHP not sending email to email addresses that have 2 dot ('.') characters in their name

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have been struggling to send an email using the mail function in PHP for a while. I want to send 2 separate emails to 2 different email addresses.

```
$allowHtmlHeader = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$allowHtmlHeader .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$headers = "From: webmaster@xyz.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@xyz.com\r\n" . $allowHtmlHeader;
$customerHeaders = "From: a.b.c@gmail.com\r\nReply-To: a.b.c@gmail.com\r\n" . $allowHtmlHeader;
$subject = "Enquiry";
$message = "Try me...";
$cMessage = "I score better!";

if ($_POST[cEmail] != null)
{
    if (mail("a.b@gmail.com", $subject, $cMessage, $cHeaders)) {
        echo("Message successfully sent!");
    }
    else {
        echo("Message delivery failed...");
    }

    if (mail("a.b.c@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo("Message successfully sent!");
    }
    else {
        echo("Message delivery failed...");
    }   
}
```

Using the above code, i could successfully send emails to a.b@gmail.com . But in all the attempts not a single mail reached a.b.c@gmail.com, though it always successfully reached a.b@gmail.com. I even tried replacing a.b@gmail.com with a.b.c@gmail.com and yet no mail was sent to that email address alone.

Maybe the mail function does not work with emails having more than 1 dot '.' in their names?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!.

Comment: If your code works with `a.b@`, but not when you change it to `a.b.c@`, then it's not a problem with your code. Do you get the 'successfully sent' messages? If so, then there'll be something happening in a mailserver somewhere along the way that's stopping the email getting through - I'd start with looking at the log on your mailserver, and see if there's anything odd there. My first guess would be that it's hitting a spam filter somewhere.

Comment: Yes I always got "Message successfully sent!". Besides, I had been trying to find spam filter on my gmail account and couldn`t find it anywhere. Also, i wonder how gmail recognizes a mailer as a spam for one account and does not care the other accounts?

Comment: Is this a gmail address problem specifically?  Gmail apparently ignores dots.   a.b.c@gmail.com == a.bc@gmail.com == abc@gmail.com.  Info here:  http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2013/08/01/dots_in_gmail_addresses_what_happens_if_you_leave_out_the_period.html

Comment: Awesome!. I removed the dots and voila!. Thanks a lot!. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

Following Pagerange`s advice, i attempted removing the dots / periods ('.') from the "to" email addresses and emails are sent flawlessly!.